# "go get" hanging on certain library

Tags: go

I'm trying to get this lumberjack library and it always hangs on the download step.

I hit the same issue Friday and today. other Go packages install fine.  I'm on Scientific Linux.  Any ideas what could be going on?

```
>go get -u -v  gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2
Fetching https://gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2"} at https://gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2?go-get=1
gopkg.in/natefinch/lumberjack.v2 (download)
```

(It hangs on last line, I've let it run for 20 minutes so far.)

Comment: It's working for me. May you have network issues. :(

Comment: Here is the result: https://gist.github.com/diatmpravin/2fa442eb37b1d34476a5

Comment: Same as @PravinMishra, I can get it just fine. Check your connection.

Comment: Thanks guys.  I'm suspecting network issues, I guess my question is more how to track down the issue, and ideally fix it :-)

Comment: @PravinMishra thanks, can I use that result somehow in place of the go get call?

Comment: You may have an old version of `git` which had some issues dealing with the meta tags. Try updating git first. (also, if you're ever stuck using 'go get' you can also just checkout the code directly into your GOPATH)

Comment: You can always manually clone to the appropriate directory

Comment: @JimB thanks for the ideas.  I'm on git 1.7.1.  Is that potentially too old?  I'll give the direct checkout a try.

Comment: @Greg: IIRC 1.7.1 is a buggy version, and quite old now.

Comment: It's [tag:go], not "Golang", and it is undesirable to [manually insert tags into question titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/150469).

Comment: I used "go get" in the title because that's the command I'm running.  I just deleted the tag though, and put "go get" in quotes.  I hope that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go command hangs indefinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033541/go-command-hangs-indefinitely)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @Jimb.  Upgrading git to a newer version fixed the issue.

Comment: Went from 2.30 -> 2.35, fixed it for me. Could also be just opening a fresh terminal, I cant tell