# Golang Revel freezes when download gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1

Tags: go, revel

I'm using CentOS7; tried downloading the golang 1.5.1 binary and also `yum install golang`, and run into the same problem installed revel. Go works fine; when I do `go version` it displays the proper version.

When I type `go get -v github.com/revel/revel`, a few packages download just fine.... until it gets to fsnotify. Then I get this output:

```
Fetching https://gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1"} at https://gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1?go-get=1
gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1 (download)
```

And it just freezes. No matter what I try, it doesn't download anything into `src/gopkg.in/fsnotify`. Files in `src/github.com` and `src/golang.org` are pulled just fine. I already made sure I'm able to curl into http://gopkg.in and https://gopkg.in, so it doesn't look like an SSLv3 issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Problem solved: git was an old version. I had tried EVERYTHING, but didn't enable rpmforge; default CentOS base repository was 1.7.1. I upgraded git and compiled from source - for sh*ts and giggles - and voila. Fixed. Good God!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["go get" hanging on certain library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895951/go-get-hanging-on-certain-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade Git so that it is greater than 1.7.1 (latest CentOS base version). Try rpmforge first; if that doesn't work, compile from source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-from-Source

I'm on Git 2.6.2 and it's working fine now: `go get -v github.com/revel/revel` (`-v` for verbose mode)