# Go command hangs indefinitely

Tags: go

When running `go run ...`, `go get ...`, etc., the process hangs and never returns. If I add the `-x` option, I only see the build stage and nothing more.

Since the last update to `go`, I've used it a bit and it worked fine. After a system restart, it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: See also [How to debug a hanging golang “go get” call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895950/how-to-debug-a-hanging-golang-go-get-call?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [“go get” hanging on certain library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895951/go-get-hanging-on-certain-library?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 12):

It took me a bit to figure out what was going on and I thought I share the problem solution here, in case somebody else encounters the problem.

As it appears in most cases, if `GOPATH` is set wrong, you'll likely get some kind of error message and the process ends. My problem was that `GOPATH` was set to a folder that should have been mounted at boot up. Not only was the path incorrect, but also the mounting of the drive failed. And exactly that was the problem. For some reason, when `GOPATH` points to an unmounted drive, you won't see an error message and the process hangs forever.

Comment: if, by mount, you mean nfs mount.  If it's a hard mount, it will hang forever (I believe).  soft mounts should error out.

Comment: @DavidBudworth: I'm mounting to a local disk not NFS

Comment: My `go list` just hangs. My `GOPATH` is set to default on my Mac. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 5):

A solution that worked for me :
If you are working with Visual Studio Code, remove the import section
and press Ctrl+S, and let the imported files list get regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Amir Leshem, removing `go.sum` and emptying `go.mod` solved the issue for me.