# go run/vet/build/test commands hang after completing. Ignores interrupt signal

Tags: go, compilation, freeze

Similar to the issue [#37033541](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37033541/go-command-hangs-indefinitely), my commands do not stop. However, my system does not have unmounted drives; my `GOPATH` is set to /users/user_name/go:/users/user_name/goCode. Neither changing this path to the installation default, nor restarting the computer, or even starting a shell without my bashrc change the behaviour. While it is running, it does generate a functional executable.

I am running go 1.14.1 installed according to the instructions for macOS Mohave.

This behaviour replicates across other packages in my system. But transferring the code to the Go Playground or another Mac computer does not replicate the behaviour. When I run `go build -x ...`, the last action is: `rm -r $WORK/b001/`.

Running a stack trace on the process yields ongoing system calls that I cannot interpret (They do seem varied and would be happy to post some if someone would think them useful).

This did not use to happen, it started a few hours ago. I would appreciate the help of someone in troubleshooting this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved only by putting in a fresh installation of the OS and then reinstalling go 1.14.1.

More here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/YxqX9o2YJ4k