# Golang. just fmt.Println in main.go，but process is blocked

Tags: macos, go

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmpzS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rftc.png)

[image]

system:macbookpro

code is very simple:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("yes")
}
```

i use "ps aux" cmd to check process, it's always in the state "S+":

```
lelingzhi        21995   0.0  0.0  4278564    752 s010  S+   11:57下午   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox main.go
lelingzhi        21979   0.0  0.1  5094512  15576 s009  S+   11:57下午   0:00.31 go run main.go
```

my GOPATH is correct:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
```

and i tried running "go run main.go" and "go run *.go" in terminal, also not work. my project run well today, just suddenly became like this

I restarted my computer，it is now normal.
But still don't know why it happened.

Comment: Did you check `GOPATH` env var?  Probably this can be the answer to the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/37033542/434255

Comment: Try running the `go run main.go` directly from the shell rather than from the IDE, if it works then you know that you just need to properly configure the GoLand IDE.

Comment: `go run *.go` will attempt to run every Go file in that directory independently one by one. That is probably not what you're trying to do. Generally, you don't want to use `go run` at all.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Go program is not in listed in the ps output. It looks like `go run` is hung for some reason.