# How to debug a hanging golang "go get" call?

Tags: go

The `go get -v gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2` is hanging after printing the following output. I could install other packages though. How to debug the root cause for this?

This has been hanging for over 6 hours. Had to come out of this by pressing cntrl+c.

```
$go get -v -insecure gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2
Fetching https://gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2"} at https://gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2?go-get=1
gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2 (download)
```

Comment: Chances are it's a `git` problem, not Go. You can set various env variables to have git log extra output (`GIT_TRACE=1` should work). It's likely an old/buggy version of git.

Comment: Closing this as this was an intermittent issue. Details are at https://github.com/urfave/cli/issues/591

Comment: Hanging is a disappointing way to handle networking issues.  BTW, here's a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29895951/go-get-hanging-on-certain-library

Answer (score 3):

Print debugging info with the **-x** flag:

```
go get -x <module>
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely a networking issue. We had this phenomenon while the connection to our ISP experienced package loss.

Since `go get` uses git, you could manually clone the repository and see what `git` tells you:

```
$ git clone --verbose https://gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is no source code repo at https://gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v2. I had to follow @Louis suggestion of cloning the repo myself

```
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/gopkg.in/urfave
cd $GOPATH/src/gopkg.in/urfave
git clone https://github.com/urfave/cli -b v2 cli.v2
```

NOTE: Opened an issue for the author https://github.com/urfave/cli/issues/591

Comment: no, that import path works. It's still probably an issue with your version of git, local git configuration, or network (proxy?).

Answer (score 0):

The nuclear option worked for me (deleting my entire $GOPATH directory and just reinstalling everything). A network issue while installing a specific package at some point caused a broken dependency and as a result go get was not working for it. This was not a big deal for me as I did not have a lot in my GOPATH, you could be more clinical about it if my approach would not be good for you.

```
# rm -rf go
```